# Regex search two different strings and replace with different values

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, text-formatting

So I need to process a string in this form:

```
<Text to be highlighted> word word word word <text again> something ...
```

So the objective is replacing all the opening **<** with a `<b>`and closing **>** with `</b>`. However I can not use two different regex one to find **<** and another to find **>** because when I run the second one the closing **>** of the recently created b tag is going to be replaced too.

I'm fully aware  that there are many workarounds with javascript and string management, however I would like to use regex for this.

Here is what I've done so far but with the issue I said before.

```
const expOpening = new RegExp(/</gm);
const expClosing = new RegExp(/>/gm);

input.replace(expOpening, '<b>');
input.replace(expClosing, '</b>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global regex replacement should work here:

```js
var input = "<Text to be highlighted> word word word word <text again> something ...";
var output = input.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, "<b>$1</b>");
console.log(input + "\n" + output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I envy you guys who master regex !

Comment: @CésarCastroAroche Check out [Wiktor's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), he is one of the top regex people on this site `:-)`